# How can I get the length (duration) of an audio file?

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager

I'm pulling media files (audio and video) into a template with Assets add-on. It doesn't appear to have the ability to grab the length (duration) of the media being uploaded. Is there a quick and easy way to get it?

Edit: [MX GetID3](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-getid3) does the trick but not for remote files. If your files are on another subdomain (as mine were), use `{server_path}` instead of `{url}` to grab the file path.

Comment: does it work for remotely hosted files though? I'm sure I tried this before with no luck

Comment: @StevenGrant Apparently it does not. I think if it sees an `http` in the URL it stops any meta processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MX GetID3](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-getid3) plugin for this purpose. This addon seems updated before 1 year but it would work.

Comment: Looks perfect, but I the download doesn't appear to work. Shucks.

Comment: Okay I found another site where I could download it. Unfortunately it doesn't accept "remote" files and since it lives on a separate subdomain, I don't think I can really fake it.

Comment: Actually it does work! I just had to use `{server_path}` instead of `{url}` to identify the file. Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it.

Comment: FYI Here's the a link to the download page: http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-getid3     Also, a given but read the manual - http://www.eec.ms/user_guide/mx-getid3/tags.html     And take note of danfo's 3rd comment regarding the URL.